# How do I prevent the splitting in half of letters when printing. (CSS)

Tags: css, printing

I'm currently working on a print-friendly page. When the page gets too long to fit on one sheet of paper, the letters get cut in half horizontally along the pages. (i.e. on the top page you can see the top half of the letters, and the bottom page you can see the bottom half of the letters.)

I tried changing the word-wrap on the words, but as expected nothing changed. I also tried settings break-inside to avoid but that didn't work either.

EDIT: This code should be able to replicate the issue with this code. If you fill the textarea to be longer than a page, and then try to print it, it should show the letters being cut in half between the first and second page.

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Can u provide minimal code to reproduce this problem?